# How to enable caching for JS, CSS files in Azure CDN for Azure App Service (Website)

Tags: azure, azure-cdn

I set up Azure CDN for Azure app service, and all works fine except caching.
I added the clientCache node as described [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/cdn-websites-with-cdn/#configure-caching-options-for-static-files-in-your-azure-web-app).

`<clientCache cacheControlMaxAge="30.00:00:00" cacheControlMode="UseMaxAge" />`

And also [set up bundles](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/cdn-websites-with-cdn/#integrate-aspnet-bundling-and-minification-with-azure-cdn) for the CDN.

The result is:
Cache works for jpeg, png.

```
Cache-Control:max-age=2592000
```

But for js and css files I get the following headers:

```
Cache-Control:no-cache
Expires:-1
Pragma:no-cache
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

From my test, it looks like Azure already enables caching of js/css caching by default. I get `Cache-Control:max-age=2592000` if I simply use the `<clientCache>` tag.

Are you saying that you're getting `Cache-Control:no-cache` from the bundled scripts/css? You should just get `Cache-Control:public` on the bundles.

I did notice that I would get `Cache-Control:no-cache` if I started playing with [caching profiles](http://www.iis.net/learn/manage/managing-performance-settings/configure-iis-7-output-caching). But that's a moot point because Azure enables js/css caching by default.